# How to resolve PCRE compilation error: range out of order in Julia?

Tags: regex, julia

suppose,

id = "ax12va-z12y-pmn8"

case a): idRegex = Regex(id)
throws error "PCRE compilation error: range out of order..."

case b): idRegex = Regex(replace(id, "-" => "\-"))
throws error "invalid escape sequence

Please help me in escaping range operator - in julia!

Comment: Change `Let id = "ax12va-z12y-pmn8"` to `Let id = "~ax12va-z12y-pmn8~"` and  Change `"\-"` to `"\\-"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
julia-1.1> id = "ax12va-z12y-pmn8"
"ax12va-z12y-pmn8"

julia-1.1> idRegex = Regex(id)
r"ax12va-z12y-pmn8"

julia-1.1> idRegex = Regex(replace(id, "-" => "\\-"))
r"ax12va\-z12y\-pmn8"
```

Try again in a fresh session, in case your previous commands have set up some inappropriate definitions.